# Running emulator not working (iOS and Phonegap)

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm trying to run a project on Xcode (4.6.2) with Phonegap (2.7).

I create the project using the create command in the terminal window, and then when I open it in Xcode and click the run button on the top left corner it builds successfully, but does not launch the emulator. Also, when I click the project tab, the "Run" button is not an option.

Any ideas as to why Xcode is not letting me run this project?

Note, I can run other projects in Xcode perfectly, it's just this one I'm having difficulty with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the create_project script and open the project for the first time in XCode, the CordovaLib sub-project is selected as the Run scheme so it builds CordovaLib OK but there's nothing to run. This has caught me out a few times and left me wondering why my project built but didn't run until I remembered to look at the scheme.

On the main toolbar at the top of Xcode, make sure the Scheme (next to Run and Stop buttons) is set to your project's name (the parent project) and not "CordovaLib" (the child project). The Scheme should read something like "My Project > iPhone" not "CordovaLib > iPhone".

Comment: Thank you! That was spot on. Just to add, I created a new scheme called the name of my project and it worked perfectly